# Warning CS0114: `AnApp.AppDelegate.Self' hides inherited member

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Today I updated to Xamarin.iOS 8.6.0.51. Now I get the following warning:

> Warning CS0114: `AnApp.AppDelegate.Self' hides inherited member`
>   MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.Self'. To make the current member
>   override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add
>   the new keyword (CS0114)

In my `AppDelegate.cs` I have defined the following property/field:

```
public static AppDelegate Self { get; private set; }
```

Than I set it in this way to get a reference to the app delegate (like proposed in  [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11712/getting-a-reference-to-the-appdelegate)):

```
AppDelegate.Self = this;
```

This worked before the update. I use this to instantiate some view controllers from the storyboard and some other things (network activity indicator, ...). What do I have to change to get this working? Don't I need this anymore or should I rename *Self*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the base class of `AppDelegate` have the member named `Self` too, compiler warns you that you may be unknowingly hiding the base class member.

If you know what you're doing then you can safely suppress the warning using `new` keyword.

```
public static new AppDelegate Self { get; private set; }
```

That makes absolutely no difference whatsoever, without the `new` keyword also your App will work the same. It just tells the c# compiler that I'm intentionally using the same name for the member and I'm interested in hiding the base class member.

Comment: The point is "If you know what you're doing" ;-). Now I'm using the `new` keyword to hide the base class member. I only don't know if this brings some side effects, because `Self` is used otherwise too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by side effects. Using new keyword is safe because otherwise also you will be hiding base class member. This just says the compiler that don't warn me, I know I'm hiding it. If someone needs to use `NSObject.Self` they need to call `NSObject.Self` rather than `AppDelegate.Self`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The app delegate plays a central role in the app development. With side effects I mean things like the Monotouch framework itself is accessing `Self`, but it has been overwritten by another instance and therefore leads to some unexpected results. Don't know if that's the case, but currently the app seems to work and therefore I accept your answer.

Comment: No, you don't need to worry about that. Monotouch framework will not have access to your `Self` instance because it is not overridden. Btw static members cannot be overridden also so you are at no risk.